# Sort data array structure in php for Czech language

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I am getting JSON in php from remote API and after that with usort i am sorting data arrays from a to z. But i need to sort it in Czech alphabet.

This is my current code:

```
     $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
     $data = json_decode( $body, true )['data']['items'];
     usort($data,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a['city'],$b['city']);});
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: This article here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1969707&seqNum=13 does sorting with a fresh alphabet. You'd prob just have to change some letters in the characters to get it up and running. If you are working with a php version that is >= 5.3 you can just use the Collator Class and just use the sort function as explained at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Yes, there is PHP 5.4. I tried it, but not working... What is wrong?           `$data = json_decode( $body, true )['data']['items'];
          $collator = new Collator('cs_CZ');
          $collator->sort($data['city']);`

Comment: You have to give a array containing all the items not just the city I would assume. Could you update your question with the $data array structure?

Comment: Question was updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide the array structure I just assumed one.

```
$data = array(
    'items' => array(
        0 => array('city' => 'Froni'),
        1 => array('city' => 'Frans'),
        2 => array('city' => 'Frédéric')
    ),
);
 usort($data['items'],
     function($a,$b) {
         $coll = collator_create( 'fr_FR' );
         $aSortKey = collator_get_sort_key($coll, $a['city']);
         $bSortKey = collator_get_sort_key($coll, $b['city']);
         return $aSortKey >= $bSortKey;
     }
 );
var_dump($data['items']);
```

This takes advantage of the Collator Sort Key rather than comparing the strings itself and is used to sort the strings within your usort anonymous function. You will most likely have to change the parameters going in the usort function and its locale, though.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you... This Collator is working as expected! So really big thanks!!

Comment: @MarekVeselý No problem glad I could help.